# PHP PDO + copy out Array

Tags: php

I have a PDO Query that returns what appears to be an array $pds. I can loop through this array as follows:

```
foreach ($pds as $row) {

 }
```

I need to loop through the same array a second time but when I do this there doesn't appear to be any data in the array. Also I've tried to copy the array as follows:

```
 $pds2 = $pds;
```

Is there a trick I'm missing to use this array twice?

thx

Code:

```
        // Remove Duplicate Locations where words are in a different order
        $cityArray = $pds;

        foreach ($cityArray as $data) {
            $words = explode(' ', $data['city'] . ' ' . $data['region1'] . ' ' . $data['region2'] . ' ' . $data['region3']);
            sort($words);
            $cityWordsArray[$data['id']] = implode(' ', $words);
        }
        $cityWordsArray = array_unique($cityWordsArray);

        foreach ($pds as $row) {
            echo 'hi';
            foreach($cityWordsArray as $key=>$value) {
                if($row['id'] == $key) {
```

Comment: Please post all your code. You must be doing something to that array that makes it unusable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid that `$pds` is not an array, but a `PDOStatement`.

If you want to get as an array, you should use `fetchAll` to get the result as an array.

Try `$pds = $pds->fetchAll();` before the loop.